# Running docker shiny app on my own domain

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, nginx, shiny

I have a VPS Linux (Ubuntu) server with specific IP and I would like to run my shiny app on my own domain http://my_domain.com. Therefore, I have built a docker container and I have run my app on the Ubuntu terminal:

```
sudo docker run -rm -p 4096:4096 my_app
```

It works well on the localhost. Then, I have modified the following lines in my Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/my_app/app',  host = 'server_ip', port = 80)"]
```

I have built and run my docker container again and I have got the following error:

```
sudo docker run --rm -p 80:80 my_app

Listening on http://server_ip:80
createTcpServer: address not available
Error in initialize(...) : Failed to create server
```

Maybe I need to configure nginx. I would be grateful if someone could tell me what would be the best solution to run my app on my own domain and how to do it.

Comment: The error is `listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use.` That means something on your host is already listening on port 80. Either stop whatever application is listening on port 80, or publish the container port on a different host port.

Answer (score 1):

Docker container does not have access to server_ip, try this :

```
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/my_app/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 80)"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the container works well on localhost with port 4096 or another port. That is not the question.

Comment: What I meant is that `host = 'server_ip'` is not right. Can you give the error message after above change ?

Comment: At the beginning, I used host="0.0.0.0" with port=4096 and it worked well, but I could use any other port, like 80. The result would be the same, it works well on localhost. The problem is to run the app on my own domain.

Comment: Have you  used host="0.0.0.0" with port=80 ? Did it work ? If not, what's the error message ?