# Docker container with shiny app listening on localhost

Tags: docker, ubuntu, shiny

I am working with a linux server and I would like to run a docker container with my shiny app, but it is not working. In order to check the problem, I have run my shiny app in RStudio with the following code:

```
shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/my_app/app', host="0.0.0.0", port=4096)
```

Then, I can see my app running on the browser an the output in the RStudio console is the following:

```
...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:4096
```

Then, I have run a docker container with my app on the Ubuntu terminal and I have got the same output:

```
sudo docker run --rm -p 4096:3838 my_app

Listening on http://0.0.0.0:4096
```

But if I navigate to this address on my browser, I cannot access to my app.

If I write the following on the Ubuntu terminal, I get:

```
curl localhost:4096

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4096
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The second `docker run -p` port number needs to match the `port=` assignment in your code.  Try `docker run -p 4096:4096`.  (The first port number can be anything, and matches the port number in your `curl` command.)

Comment: Thanks! Now, I would like to see my app on my own domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-p xxxx:yyyy` parameter on the `docker run` command maps the internal container port (yyyy) to a port on the host machine (xxxx).

Your app listens on port 4096 which is the internal port. It looks like you want to access the app on localhost:4096, so the host port should also be 4096.

Try

```
sudo docker run --rm -p 4096:4096 my_app
```

Comment: Great! it works. How could I see my app running on my own domain?

Comment: You'd need the docker host to be reachable from the internet and you'd need the DNS entry for the domain to point to the IP address of the docker host.

Comment: Docker host? I have edited another question and I would like to get an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151430/running-docker-shiny-app-on-my-own-domain